# Resize image or write a couple of extra lines of javascript...which one is more expensive?

Tags: javascript, image-processing

On one part of my site, the click of a button (function LoadPic() ) loads the chosen user's photo (userpic) into a div (PicHolder) of given dimensions. By necessity for my site the loaded image (userpic) must have dimensions smaller than the user's Gallery/Profile image size when they upload a photo for their profile. The default image (no uploaded user Profile photo = **images/NoPic.jpg**) can easily be resized on my end (to **images/NoPicSmall.jpg**) by a graphics program. For website speed, would I be better off resizing all loaded images (including the default image, NoPic.jpg) in the innerHTML of LoadPic() (with fewer lines of code) as follows:

```
function LoadPic(userpic) {    
    document.getElementById('PicHolder').innerHTML = '<img src="' + userpic + '"     
style="width:60px;height:66px" alt="user picture">';    
}
```

OR writing a few extra lines of code to save on image resizing for users who have **images/NoPic.jpg** as their image?

```
function LoadPic(userpic) {
    if (userpic === 'images/NoPic.jpg') {
        document.getElementById('PicHolder').innerHTML = '<img   
src="images/NoPicSmall.jpg" alt="user picture">';    
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('PicHolder').innerHTML = '<img src="' + userpic + '"     
style="width:60px;height:66px" alt="user picture">';    
    }
}//End function
```

My understanding is that image resizing is relatively expensive computationally so anywhere I can load an image where the dimensions are already correct, this is worth it. In other words, the computational savings in not resizing the default user image in the second function would be of greater benefit than writing more lines of code. Am I way off here? Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is no computational advantage anywhere, as using HTML `width` and `height` styles will do nothing with the original image--it will just scale it down. So if you had a full HD image, and resized it down with HTML/CSS, it would download the *entire* image in the dimensions you specified.

Comment: I should have said scaling...doesn't the scaling require processing that an image not needing scaling does not require?

Comment: Yes, but that is on the client side, and there is minimal (if any) time needed to resize. You can do a few tests out yourself if you wish.

Comment: I think the advantage of not scaling, if there is any, would be very minimal. You're better off creating re-sized images server side using a library like imagemagic or gd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some code server-side to upload portraits, that's where you should resize the images.

Resize computations take a neglectible amount of time, but the memory used for your pictures and the image download time are more of a problem.

If some user uploads a 1 terabytes picture, it should be reduced to proper dimensions on the server, so that the browser don't get 1Tb to download and store in memory just to display a handful of pixels in the end.

As for the `images/NoPic.jpg`, well... You should have a bunch of user profile infos somewhere, so you could simply keep an information telling a user has not uploaded any portrait yet, and provide your `NoPic` image in that case.